# How to display relation data into json format from two database table in rest api and yii2

Tags: mysql, angularjs, rest, yii2

My database structure

**Departments** table contain

1. department_id
2. department

**Doctor** table contain

1. department_id

**Doctor.php** //Model Name

```
public function fields() {
    return [
        'doctor_id',
        'd_name',
        'email',
        'phone',
        'speciality',
        'department' => function ($model) {
            return $model->department->department; // Return related model property, correct according to your structure
        },
        'qualification',
        'profile_image',
        'experience',  
    ];
}
```

**web.php**

```
[
    'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
    'controller' => ['doctor','department'],
],
```

JSON data

```
 [
    {
        "doctor_id":1,
         "d_name":"Saurabh Joshi",
         "email":"****@gmail.com",
         "phone":0,
         "speciality":"1",
         "department_id":"1",
         "qualification":"M.S. (General Surgery) – Marathwada University\n    MBBS – Marathwada University",
         "profile_image":"Saurabh_Joshi1-1439384488.jpg",
         "experience":""
    }
]
```

I want `department name` in instead of `department_id` when I fetch data from doctors table to show on form.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about it but you may try.

In **Doctor.php** model

```
public function getDepartment()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Department::className(), ['department_id' => 'department_id']);
}
```

and in `fields()`

```
public function fields() {
    return [
        'doctor_id',
        'd_name',
        'email',
        'phone',
        'speciality',
        'department' => 'department.department',
        //or
        'Department' => 'department' => function () {
            return $this->getDepartment->department;
        },
        'qualification',
        'profile_image',
        'experience',  
    ];
}
```